# How can I boot EFI USB on virtualbox?

Tags: boot, usb, virtualbox

I have a Windows external drive and I want to boot the system on it. How can I do that? I've tried using PLboot and rEFInd and it does nothing.

Comment: You can't. Virtualbox creates and uses a virtual disk to boot. An EFI USB can be booted via the BIOS.

Comment: For now I only have one way to boot EFI USB, install new smallest linux distro with grub 2 included  then update grub and boot using linux grub but it consumes a lot of my linux drive space, is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can, there are various ways, one implies using a VirtualCD iso image that will let you jump to USB booting; another one implies creating a special virtual hard disk VMDK that point to you real external HDD (technically it is not booting from USB, it is booting from a VirtualHDD whose sectors are on the USB one).

But if you are up to configure Grub2, why on the hell you need a full mini distro? Just use a small 8MiB (also a 2Mib can be enought) with Grub2 and put on grub.cfg a menu to load OS from USB drive, all drives (fixed, internal, external, usb are seen by Grub2 in the same way).

Seach for grub2-install and parameters --boot-directory and --efi-directory (in case you want [U]EFI booting).

So inside VirtualBOX you only need a small Virtual Hard Disk (just for Grub2, no need of a working Linux) that will boot the Grub2 bootloader.

Beware, if you want to boot Windows from that external drive, better use de trick of creating a Virtual Hard disk that point to real external hard disk (the file is a vmdk)... do not forget to run VirtualBox in elevated (if host is Windows).

Search: VirtualBox Boot USB with wmdk virtual disk.

Hope i could help.